# What is WPF equivalent of WinForm Strings?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-to-c#

How do I convert the following VB WinForm to C# WPF?

```
txtFoo.Text = Strings.Right(txtFoo.Text, 10000)
```

I cannot find `Strings` in WPF control class and `String` in WPF does not have method of `String.Right`

Comment: your question before was  on *completely* different subject.

Comment: You cannot invalidate posted answers by changing the question.

Comment: sorry guys, I wanted to delete the question but answers come in too quick already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
 txtFoo.Text = txtFoo.Text.Substring(txtFoo.Text.Length - 10000);
```

Of course you need to check if the length of the string is greater than 10000

Answer (score 3):

It is a VB.NET convenience method.  Project + Add Reference, select Microsoft.VisualBasic and put

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

at the top of your source code file.

A C# version of that same code would look like this:

```
    if (txtFoo.Text.Length > 10000) {
        txtFoo.Text = txtFoo.Text.Substring(txtFoo.Text.Length - 10000);
    }
```

Comment: Why do to just use a `substring` ??

Comment: Erm, I posted a snippet with SubString().  If you find the namespace objectionable for some reason, do check the upvoted post for a bug that will make the OP's life miserable.  A bug that won't happen when he just uses Right().  And others, presumably.

Comment: my point was not about  *concrete*  C# function, but why  do not use a host language constructs and instead add a reference to VB.

Comment: There's no concept of "host language" in .NET.  Framework classes like String and Strings work equally well in C#, VB, F#, J#, C++/CLI and any other language port.  That's a *very* nice feature of .NET, there's no point in throwing goodies in other assemblies away because the namespace sounds wrong.

Comment: ok :)  you trick on my *non accurate* english. Saying "host", I mean C# available. `Strings` is not avalable **in C#**, by yhe way I understand your point.

Comment: Of course it is.  Add the reference.  Surely you added references to your own projects before?  Are the classes in them "not available in C#" as well?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with WinForms.  You can use that method just fine.  Just reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and add a using directive to the same thing.

You certainly can replace it with System.String calls.  But it's fine to use that assembly from C# if you want.